# Android - Creating a Timer loop for a pong game

Tags: android, loops, timer, android-asynctask, pong

I have a **Pong** game that I wrote in Java and I'm trying to port it to Android. (It's my first Android game ;).

In Java I used a `Timer` object which basically updated the Game values (ball/paddles position) and then redrew the screen.

I'm trying to implement the same functionality in Android but I'm getting a number of errors.

My program consists of a `PongView` class which is the visual part of the game, and a `PongDriverActivity` class which uses `PongView` for its view. If I have a looping thread invalidating `PongView` I get an error because the thread can't touch a view spawned on another thread.

I assume I need to do some sort of `AsyncTask`, but I'm not sure how to loop that.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do this.  Android does support normal Java `Thread` objects, and you *can* use those.  You can search (SO) for `android game loop` and probably find lots of examples.  But, if you'd like to try `AsyncTask`, here's a sample implementation:

```
public class PongView extends View {

    public PongView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }    
    public void setBallPosition(int x, int y) {
        // relocate the ball graphic
    }    
}
```

Then, your Activity:

```
public class PongDriverActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private enum GameSpeed { SLOW, MEDIUM, FAST };

    private PongView mGameView;
    private PongDriverTask mWorker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGameView = new PongView(this);
        mWorker = new PongDriverTask(GameSpeed.MEDIUM);

        // if you need to pass some data to the worker:
        mWorker.execute("one", "two", "three");  
        // else, declare the AsyncTask's first generic param as Void, and do:
        //mWorker.execute();

        setContentView(mGameView);
    }

    // you would connect this up to a button, to allow the user to stop  
    public void onStopClicked(View sender) {
        if (mWorker.isRunning()) {
            mWorker.stopRunning();
        }
    }

    // you could connect this up to a slider, to allow the user to control the paddle
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // you may need to convert progress to a y-coordinate
        mWorker.setPaddlePosition(progress);
    }
```

And, then (maybe inside PongDriverActivity.java, an inner class):

```
private class PongDriverTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    private int mDelay;
    private boolean mRunning = true;
    private int mPaddleY = 0;

    public PongDriverTask(GameSpeed speed) {
        if (speed == GameSpeed.SLOW) {
            mDelay = 100;
        } else if (speed == GameSpeed.MEDIUM) {
            mDelay = 50;
        } else if (speed == GameSpeed.FAST) {
            mDelay = 10;
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
        return mRunning;
    }
    public synchronized void stopRunning() {
        mRunning = false;
    }
    public synchronized void setPaddlePosition(int y) {
        mPaddleY = 0;
    }
    private synchronized int getPaddlePosition() {
        return mPaddleY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer score) {
        super.onPostExecute(score);
        // here you could show a UI that shows the final score
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mGameView.setBallPosition(0, 0);
        // here you could throw up some UI that shows just
        //  before the game really starts
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(params);
        // retrieve updated game coordinates from params
        mGameView.setBallPosition(params[0], params[1]);  // x,y
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
        // If you have some information to pass to the background worker, 
        //  it would be passed in args[0], args[1], etc.
        // It doesn't have to be String data.  you could change the generic 
        //  to take something other than String as the first param, in which
        //  case, doInBackground() would take a variable length list of that
        //  other data type.
        int ballX = 0;
        int ballY = 0;
        int score = 0;

        while (isRunning()) {
            // use your game engine to recalculate the ball position
            //  on this background thread
            int paddleY = getPaddlePosition();
            ballX += 1;
            ballY += 2;
            score++;

            // now, update the UI, which must happen on the UI thread
            publishProgress(ballX, ballY);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(mDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

The task's `doInBackground()` method will be run on a background thread, so you must not directly modify the UI from there.  But, all the other `AsyncTask` methods I override above are called on the UI thread, so it's safe to perform UI work in any of them.

This code assumes the paddle is controlled by a seek bar, which you'd make your `Activity` a change listener for.  Lots of other ways to do it, too.

I just implemented a crude game stop mechanism, which you could hook up to a button.  If you want to allow the user to pause and resume, you can search for implementations to pause/resume threads, which should be applicable here, too.  For example:

[How to Pause and Resume a Thread in Java from another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11989589/119114)

### More Reading ...

[See this writeup for some discussion of game loop speeds](http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-game-loops) ...

[and maybe take a look at this discussion, too](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/21205)