# Doing a Timed action without Interrupting the Main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I have a Thread that needs to continuously run, however when a certain action is called, I want to wait 500ms, and then do another action, without interrupting the main Thread. Is there any way to do so?

I immediately thought of creating an just restarting a new Thread each time, but this doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: There seems to be a confusion with the question, so let me elaborate. I have a thread that is contiously working. When and action is preformed, a method is called. In that method I need to wait for 500ms and then call another method, without interrupting the main thread. This also has to be re-usable.

Comment: **I want to wait 500ms, and then do another action**, can you please elaborate this?

Comment: Can you write some pseudo code elaborating your question. Still not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quartz` is an scheduler that allows you to:

> ... create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds,
>   or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as
>   standard Java components that may execute virtually anything you may
>   program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many
>   enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions and
>   clustering.

You can implement scheduled jobs to run in a certain given time. Here you can find some tutorials and more info:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

This might give you the idea of how to handle similar situations:

[How to Pause and Resume a Thread in Java from another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989589/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-thread-in-java-from-another-thread)