# Multithreading: wait() and notify() in Java WITHOUT checkpoints everywhere?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have two threads in two different classes, Thread1 and Thread2.

In Thread 1 I have something like this:

```
public class Thread1
{
    public static boolean pause = false;
    public void run()
    {

        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (myLock)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    //a for loop
                }

                if (someCondition1)
                {
                    //an if statement
                }

                while (someCondition2)
                {
                    //a while loop
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Thread 2 I have something like this:

```
public void run()
    {
        Thread1.pause=true;
        synchronized(myLock)
        {
            //do some mutually exclusive task while Thread1 waits
        }
        Thread1.pause=false;

        myLock.notify();
    }
}
```

Of course, Thread1.start(); and Thread2.start(); happen elsewhere in another program, but assume both threads are started.

The problem is I don't know where to put my wait() in Thread 1.

What I want: Thread 2 to be able to interrupt Thread1 regardless of where I am in Thread1. If I have in total 100 for loops, while loops and if statements in Thread1's run() method, I DON'T want to put a checkpoint

```
if (paused)
{
  wait();
}
```

inside every one of those loops in Thread1. Is there a way to pause Thread1's run() method regardless of which loop/if statement I am in? (i.e. regardless of where I am currently in Thread1?)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have 100 `for` loops in thread 1, or is that just exaggerating for effect?  Assuming you're writing something reasonably sane, the approach you've outlined in your question seems perfectly sensible.  If it's a nested loop, check for pause in the outer loop.

Comment: ok sorry that is a bit of an exaggeration, but I really do have a lot of loops and if statements.. and nested loops and nested statements in Thread1's run()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989589

Comment: Basically I would like an infinite number of checkpoints "wait()" in Thread1's run() but that is not practical....

Comment: In a kaveri APU, you may be able to use Thread1 as opencl(jocl/aparapi) kernel of "integrated gpu" and control myLock from CPU-cores(conventional threads). You may need to pass myLock as a kernel-parameter to have same address though.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to pause the Thread? Because I am sure this is more like an architectural issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the ability to `suspend` a thread at any moment, at the command of another thread. That ability has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29) for a long time now, due to its unsafety.

So yes, you actually *do* have to manually insert checkpoints into your code where it is safe for the thread to enter the waiting state. Multithreading is a rough terrain and there's no royal way about it.