# Nothing happening in event dispatch thread after executing SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading

In my quest to understand concurrency in Java.  I created a program with a GUI that has a JTextArea named `display`.

There is also a `JButton` that one clicks to open a secondary frame to play with a `JProgressBar` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371077/how-to-use-jbuttons-to-start-and-pause-swingworker-thread)).

The `ActionListener` for the button that opens the new frame includes this code:

```
SwingWorker<String, Void> openProgressorGUI = 
        new SwingWorker<String, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ProgressorGUI bp = new ProgressorGUI();
        bp.setVisible(true);
        bp.pack();
        return null;
    }

};
openProgressorGUI.execute();

display.append("You just opened the Progress Bar window”);
```

When the button is clicked, the secondary frame opens and does what it needs to, but the `display` in the main GUI doesn't print "You just opened the Progress Bar window".

My understanding is that a SwingWorker opens a new background thread so the event dispatch thread is not interrupted.

Why isn't control continuing past the `SwingWorker` to finish the code in the `ActionListener`?

Comment: Did you read and understand [*this*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) and [*this*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)? `doInBackground()` is, as the name suggests, for performing *background* tasks, *not* for manipulating the GUI.

Comment: I have indeed read both.  I'm confused how it applies to my situation.  I (perhaps mistakenly) feel like opening a new frame should not interfere with the current frame.  Clearly I'm not understanding the event dispatch thread.

Comment: There is no exception for frames. Everything which belongs the the GUI should be accessed by exactly one thread, the EDT.